# Capture all Click or Touch events recursively in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, pixelsense

am pretty new to WPF, but am looking to capture whenever anyone touches inside a window or any child controls.

If I capture the click event for a Window, only the windows inner space capture the click. It's child controls do not.

How do i recursively capture any click/touch event ANYWHERE on the screen in a full size window?

many thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The routed event handling implementation in WPF is intended to give all controls in a nested hierarchy a chance to intercept and handle touch & mouse events. However, controls have the ability to prevent children from receiving the event notification.

There's a pretty good explanation of event routing here: http://nui.joshland.org/2010/04/why-wont-wpf-controls-work-with-touch.html

All controls receive a Preview event (for click or touch), and this cannot be prevented. After this, the event is 'promoted' to a regular Mouse/Touch event (touch is handled before click) However, if any control in the hierarchy for the 'click' (_MouseDown in WPF) event handling sets the **Handled** property on the event args to true, then the event will not be propagated any further.

Unless you are handling touch events or manipulations, or explicitly setting **e.Handled = true** in your code, then all controls in a nested stack should receive the _MouseDown event.

As noted in the comments below, some controls will set 'Handled = true' which would prevent their *containers* from receiving corresponding _TouchDown or _MouseDown events. However, they would *all* receive a PreviewTouch/PreviewMouseDown first.

Also note that handling touch events prevents handling of mouse events.

Comment: Buttons, checkboxes, etc., will "Handle" the events for you.  That's what the Preview events are for.

Comment: True, but that's the inverse problem to what the OP notes; "only the window captures the click". B